# What is the interpretation of an infinite formal context-free grammar?

Tags: fl.formal-languages, grammars, context-free

Let $L$ be a language as follows:

$$
\begin{align*}
L  &::= a\ |\ L^{*}\\
\end{align*}
$$

Now, suppose I apply some sort of transformation $T : N \rightarrow N$ where $N$ is the set of non-terminals in the grammar. Suppose that this results in $L$ being transformed into a modified version of $L$ by adding a unique prefix and postfix terminal to the $L^{*}$, and adding that new alternative parse to the grammar.

$$
\begin{align*}
L  &::=  &  a\ |\ L^{*}\\
   &\ |  & (hello)\  L^{*}\ (bye)
\end{align*}
$$

As we apply $T$ infinitely many times to the context-free grammar, where the added terminals can be any arbitrary pairs of strings:

$$
\begin{align*}
L  &::=  &  a\ |\ L^{*}\\
   &\ |  & (hello)\  L^{*}\ (bye)\\
   &\ |  & (hi)\  L^{*}\ (goodbye)\\
   &\ |  & (begin)\  L^{*}\ (end)\\
   &     \vdots & \vdots
\end{align*}
$$

...is the resulting grammar still context-free or is it now context-sensitive?

In short -- if a grammar has an infinite set of prefix/postfix pairs for a given non-terminal, is it a context-free grammar?

Comment: Absolutely not. The grammar may even become highly undecidable.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Particularly the case I'm trying to model is that of XML without a schema. The matching tags component forces an infinite set of possible parse trees in the context-free grammar formalism as every single tag of the form `< identifier >` has a matching and unique tag "terminal" `< / identifier >`.